# Ubuntu missing from the Grub menu

Tags: 12.04, grub2

Recently I've had some audio issues with Ubuntu (using precise), and in the process of trying to resolve that I ran a dist-upgrade. Everything went just fine, and the sound seemed good, until I rebooted my machine for the first time since the dist-upgrade.

All I see now in the Grub menu at startup is `memtest86+`, another `memtest` variant, and Windows 7. It's not showing any of the linux kernels that Ubuntu is running on.

I am attaching my `bootinfoscript`:

```
    Boot Info Script 0.61.full + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info November 20th 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos6)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Dell Utility: FAT16
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda6 
                       and looks at sector 220046240 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       for (,msdos6)/boot/grub on this drive.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63       273,104       273,042  de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2    *        274,432    19,406,847    19,132,416   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          19,406,848   218,274,364   198,867,517   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         218,275,838   625,139,711   406,863,874   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5         328,630,272   625,139,711   296,509,440   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6         218,275,840   324,030,463   105,754,624  83 Linux
/dev/sda7         324,032,512   328,626,175     4,593,664  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        07DA-0512                              vfat       DellUtility
/dev/sda2        8834146034145392                       ntfs       RECOVERY
/dev/sda3        48E2189DE21890F4                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda5        BC2A44C02A447982                       ntfs       Varshneya
/dev/sda6        34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c   ext4       
/dev/sda7        dcb9ce9b-799a-4c65-b008-887b01775670   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda6        /mnt                     ext4       (rw)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c
if loadfont /boot/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8834146034145392
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=dcb9ce9b-799a-4c65-b008-887b01775670 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 104.851909637 = 112.583880704  boot/grub/core.img                             1
 121.191410065 = 130.128285696  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4

00000000  eb 0f 2a 5d f4 b7 75 f2  e9 56 12 b8 50 b4 79 ec  |..*]..u..V..P.y.|
00000010  89 91 ca c3 16 40 31 d0  ae c4 53 3d c7 dd d7 98  |.....@1...S=....|
00000020  bd a4 f2 a4 e8 ab fc ea  36 30 1b 34 cf 8a 28 30  |........60.4..(0|
00000030  43 95 6c 31 3e 76 93 58  84 37 99 c3 ae 3a 88 a3  |C.l1>v.X.7...:..|
00000040  c2 a6 36 2a f8 e0 e1 03  91 8d a1 50 cd ad b0 b5  |..6*.......P....|
00000050  ad 69 3a 49 63 1f 4a 33  97 6e 0c 71 bf 7d bd 35  |.i:Ic.J3.n.q.}.5|
00000060  86 c5 17 93 b4 9f e5 af  e0 c4 6f f4 6f f9 4b dd  |..........o.o.K.|
00000070  14 39 e2 9e b9 36 ca b1  56 5b d9 b1 66 2c 05 b2  |.9...6..V[..f,..|
00000080  5d 5b 99 c0 db e6 81 27  ab c2 e1 55 00 ac 0b 2c  |][.....'...U...,|
00000090  24 d3 8e 54 b0 3d ab 58  e4 23 fc 3a 79 93 fb 5e  |$..T.=.X.#.:y..^|
000000a0  94 5a 3a c2 16 4e 56 cb  1b 7f 7e b3 4c 38 ca 5b  |.Z:..NV...~.L8.[|
000000b0  ca ab c1 2c 2a 64 e7 77  fe 2a ba ee 08 33 b5 9b  |...,*d.w.*...3..|
000000c0  d0 c2 b4 a8 fc 73 4f 01  fd 03 61 75 eb 6d 1a 74  |.....sO...au.m.t|
000000d0  5f 79 31 7f ed e6 f5 99  21 36 16 ed 25 d9 6d 2b  |_y1.....!6..%.m+|
000000e0  5f f4 42 b8 9d 01 89 10  fe df a4 98 e7 ab ab ea  |_.B.............|
000000f0  1d 1c 44 e1 49 d9 19 c9  ab f5 41 eb 4a 32 c2 39  |..D.I.....A.J2.9|
00000100  87 57 f6 f6 f3 b5 4d 17  72 f2 b1 16 19 aa ec 24  |.W....M.r......$|
00000110  39 bd e3 b1 68 b3 b0 7f  fa 2a 3a 2e 99 ed db 8a  |9...h....*:.....|
00000120  f8 61 b4 ef 9d 7d 85 95  ed ad eb 9e 71 f4 27 d3  |.a...}......q.'.|
00000130  f3 04 8b 8a 69 98 02 72  df e1 f9 83 27 5b 01 4c  |....i..r....'[.L|
00000140  d4 9a b9 3b db ca 1e 40  35 db 6f c1 52 c0 7f 27  |...;...@5.o.R..'|
00000150  8a 1d bc 34 89 24 b6 e3  fd ec a1 2a e5 9e d1 8f  |...4.$.....*....|
00000160  77 e0 d5 52 c0 4c c4 38  38 3c 28 19 bf 20 f0 03  |w..R.L.88<(.. ..|
00000170  38 a4 b1 b5 ed 6a b8 f7  a9 7b 65 b1 7b 64 4a 33  |8....j...{e.{dJ3|
00000180  66 1a 60 29 38 1d 5b 52  40 31 de a5 0c 0f cc 6f  |f.`)8.[R@1.....o|
00000190  dd 31 6d 3d f0 2a 32 85  67 66 ca 4f 02 aa 0d 30  |.1m=.*2.gf.O...0|
000001a0  66 c9 b2 33 c2 4b 8a fa  3c 7b 52 02 00 88 8e cf  |f..3.K..<{R.....|
000001b0  67 1e d4 20 49 1d 1a b8  71 ad c2 d4 37 9d 00 fe  |g.. I...q...7...|
000001c0  ff ff 07 fe ff ff 02 e0  93 06 00 60 ac 11 00 fe  |...........`....|
000001d0  ff ff 05 fe ff ff 01 00  00 00 01 b0 4d 06 00 00  |............M...|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200



ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2012-11-24__09h45 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.195~ppa2~precise
boot-sav version : 3.195~ppa2~precise
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa45~precise
boot-sav-extra version : 3.195~ppa2~precise
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, precise, Ubuntu, i686)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda6:Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (12.04):Ubuntu:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DellUtility" UUID="07DA-0512" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="8834146034145392" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="48E2189DE21890F4" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Varshneya" UUID="BC2A44C02A447982" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda6: UUID="34731459-4b0f-46ac-a9bf-cb360a2c947c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda7: UUID="dcb9ce9b-799a-4c65-b008-887b01775670" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660"


1 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Windows not detected by os-prober on sda3.
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.


=================== /mnt/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"




=================== /mnt/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root     4096 Nov 22 16:15 grub.d
total 56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6743 Sep 12 20:19 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5522 Sep 12 20:05 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7407 Sep 12 20:19 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6335 Sep 12 20:19 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1588 Sep 24  2010 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7603 Sep 12 20:19 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  214 Sep 12 20:19 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   95 Sep 12 20:19 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  483 Sep 12 20:19 README


=================== No kernel in /mnt/boot:
grub
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+_multiboot.bin


=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not EFI-compatible.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.
sda3    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda3.
sda5    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda5.
sda6    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc,    update-grub,    64, no-kernel,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 63 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA ST9320423AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      32.3kB  140MB   140MB   primary   fat16           diag
2      141MB   9936MB  9796MB  primary   ntfs            boot
3      9936MB  112GB   102GB   primary   ntfs
4      112GB   320GB   208GB   extended                  lba
6      112GB   166GB   54.1GB  logical   ext4
7      166GB   168GB   2352MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
5      168GB   320GB   152GB   logical   ntfs


Model: HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GA31N (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 4700MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      131kB  2916MB  2916MB  primary               boot, hidden

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:320GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST9320423AS;
1:32.3kB:140MB:140MB:fat16::diag;
2:141MB:9936MB:9796MB:ntfs::boot;
3:9936MB:112GB:102GB:ntfs::;
4:112GB:320GB:208GB:::lba;
6:112GB:166GB:54.1GB:ext4::;
7:166GB:168GB:2352MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
5:168GB:320GB:152GB:ntfs::;

BYT;
/dev/sr0:4700MB:scsi:2048:2048:msdos:HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GA31N;
1:131kB:2916MB:2916MB:::boot, hidden;


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sda6 on /mnt type ext4 (rw)
/dev on /mnt/dev type none (rw,bind)
/proc on /mnt/proc type none (rw,bind)
/sys on /mnt/sys type none (rw,bind)
/usr on /mnt/usr type none (rw,bind)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type vfat (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency disk dri dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse fw0 hidraw0 hpet input kmsg log mapper mcelog mei mem net network_latency network_throughput null oldmem port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uinput urandom usbmon0 usbmon1 usbmon2 v4l vga_arbiter video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  1.9G  113M  1.8G   6% /
udev           devtmpfs   1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      777M  872K  776M   1% /run
/dev/sr0       iso9660    696M  696M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   667M  667M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.9G   20K  1.9G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      1.9G  176K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6      ext4        51G   27G   22G  56% /mnt
/dev/sda1      vfat       134M  9.1M  125M   7% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk    9.2G  5.6G  3.6G  61% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3      fuseblk     95G   80G   16G  84% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda5      fuseblk    142G  130G   12G  92% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb8000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63      273104      136521   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *      274432    19406847     9566208    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        19406848   218274364    99433758+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       218275838   625139711   203431937    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       328630272   625139711   148254720    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       218275840   324030463    52877312   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       324032512   328626175     2296832   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order


=================== Repair blockers
64bits detected. Please use this software in a 64bits session. (Please use Ubuntu-Secure-Remix-64bits (www.sourceforge.net/p/ubuntu-secured) which contains a 64bits-compatible version of this software.) This will enable this feature.
=================== Final advice in case of recommended repair


The boot files of [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

=================== Default settings
Recommended-Repair
This setting would reinstall the grub2 of sda6 into the MBR of sda, using the following options:     kernel-purge
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot

=================== Settings chosen by the user
Boot-Info
This setting will not act on the MBR.



No change has been performed on your computer. See you soon!
pastebinit  packages needed
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
pastebin.com ko (), using paste.ubuntu Please report this message to yannubuntu@gmail.com
```

Any help would be great, I'm really missing Ubuntu (hate being stuck in the Windows world).

**EDIT**: Just checked my /boot/ folder through the Live CD, and the only two .bin files there are the memtest ones. Is this relevant? Where would the linux kernel images usually be installed to?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the links below. They have helped me. Can help you as well.

Win7 installed first and Win7 still controlling startup after Linux installation ( http://thpc.info/dual/win7/dualboot_win7+ubuntu1210_bcd_on_win7.html )

or

Windows 7 installed first and Ubuntu's GRUB2 on Windows partition controlling startup
http://thpc.info/dual/win7/dualboot_win7+ubuntu1210_grub_mbr_on_win7.html

www linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/comment-page-5/#comments

Comment: That looks like a great resource. But the problem, I think, is that it can't find my linux kernel images. This wasn't a fresh install, I was just updating some resources and ran a long overdue dist-upgrade. That just really messed things up.

Comment: @Dhan please don't just post links. Actually copy and paste the relevant text, in case a link goes dead.